# Casting Iterator with generics to Iterator with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, iterator, wildcard

I am trying to cast an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<T>>>` to an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<?>>>` because I cannot declare a generic T in my code. I am getting the following error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<capture#6-of ?>>> to Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<?>>>

I have a class `OptionSet<T>` that I am getting my `Iterator` from:

```
public class OptionSet<T> implements Iterable<Map<String,Option<T>>> {

  private final Map<String,Option<T>> options;

  // ...

  public final Iterator<Map<String,Option<T>>> iterator() {
    return options.entrySet().iterator();
  }

}
```

I am using an `OptionSet<?>` in my code, so I don't have a generic type.
I am trying to get an `Iterator` from this class:

```
final Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<?>>> iterator = optionSet.iterator();
```

For some reason Java does not allow this. Casting is not allowed either. However, the following works:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
final Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<?>>> iterator = (Iterator) optionSet.iterator();
```

So, why does this work, but won't Java allow the normal converting or casting?

Comment: Probably because your `iterator` method returns a `Iterator<Map<String,Option<T>>>` when it should return `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<T>>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a type T in your code. That just stands in for "Type". Meaning it is a typed object. How the assignment works depends on how your OptionSet is getting instantiated. For example this works:

```
    OptionSet<String> optionSet = new OptionSet<>();
    final Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<String>>> iterator = optionSet.iterator();
```

And this works because you aren't assigning a type to the generic in the OptionSet when it is instantiated so it is typeless from a generic standpoint so the capture on the assignment can be anything

```
        OptionSet optionSet = new OptionSet<>();
        final Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<?>>> iterator = optionSet.iterator();
```

And if for some reason you don't know what the type is when instantiated you can still use it generically. Just make use the generic type definition and it will hold whatever was passed in. For example:

```
public void testUnknownTypeOptionSet(OptionSet<T> testOptionSet) {

        final Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<T>>> iterator = testOptionSet.iterator();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I asked why `(Iterator) optionSet.iterator()` works and `(Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Option<?>>>) optionSet.iterator()` doesn't. Also, in my case I don't have a generic type where I am getting the iterator, because I only have an `OptionSet<?>`.

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `optionSet` or how it is arriving to know why it doesn't work specifically. Generally, you are running into this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: I take the `OptionSet<?>` from from a `Map<OptionType<?>,OptionSet<?>>`

Comment: In that case you should be using the third option in my answer above with the generic T for type. You don't need a ? capture on the variable assignment. At the point you create the iterator the value is typed even if you don't know what it is.